# Add PHP variable inside echo statement as href link address?

Tags: php, variables, echo, href, double-quotes

I'm trying to use a PHP variable to add a href value for a link in an echo statement.

Here's a simplified version of the code I want to use. I know that I can't just add the variable into the echo statement, but I can't seem to find an example anywhere that works.

```
$link_address = '#';
echo '<a href="$link_address">Link</a>';
```

Comment: If you switched your single `'` and double quotes `"` around this would work.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try like

**HTML in PHP :**

```
echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Link</a>";
```

Or even you can try like

```
echo "<a href='$link_address'>Link</a>";
```

Or you can use PHP in HTML like

**PHP in HTML :**

```
<a href="<?php echo $link_address;?>"> Link </a>
```

Comment: if you use double quotes, why use concatenation for a variable?

Comment: Yup.Now I have added that too...We can use either.Thanks @eis

Comment: The second suggestion here (`echo "<a href='$link_address'>Link</a>";`) which is nice and simple and works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

you can either use

```php
echo '<a href="'.$link_address.'">Link</a>';
```

or

```php
echo "<a href=\"$link_address\">Link</a>';
```

if you use double quotes you can insert the variable into the string and it will be parsed.

Answer (score 5):

Basically like this,

```
<?php
$link = ""; // Link goes here!
print "<a href="'.$link.'">Link</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

as simple as that: `echo '<a href="'.$link_address.'">Link</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one and more echo statement inside href

```
<a href="profile.php?usr=<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']."&email=". $_SESSION['email']; ?> ">Link</a>
```

link : "/profile.php?usr=firstname&email=email"

Answer (score 0):

This worked much better in my case.

HTML in PHP: `<a href=".$link_address.">Link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to generate links in PHP is to use the built-in function [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). This function is very easy to use and takes an array as an argument.

To create a dynamic link simply echo out the result of `http_build_query()` like so:

```
$data = [
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name
];

echo '<a href="index.php?'.http_build_query($data).'">Link</a>';
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print in the tabular form with, then you can use this:

```
echo "<tr> <td><h3> ".$cat['id']."</h3></td><td><h3> ".$cat['title']."<h3></</td><td> <h3>".$cat['desc']."</h3></td><td><h3> ".$cat['process']."%"."<a href='taskUpdate.php' >Update</a>"."</h3></td></tr>" ;
```