# inserting php variable in link

Tags: php, url

Please help me to solve this.

I am trying to insert a variable inside the link

the `$keyword` variable stands for keywords to search in a specific website
here is my code:

```
$keyword =$_COOKIE['keyword'];
$digikeyurl = 'http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors?keywords="'.$keyword. '"';
```

it doesn't have any error but my problem is, it is not executing properly.

thanks and more power!

Comment: This is liable to injection attacks.

Comment: @GeorgeSimms How's that?

Comment: I hope this may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916966/add-php-variable-inside-echo-statement-as-href-link-address

Comment: Can you give us an example for `$keyword` variable ? please Maybe you should apply an [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on $keyword to convert all non-alphanumeric characters except -_

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$digikeyurl = 'http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors?keywords='.$keyword;
```

Comment: are you sure, `$keyword` has value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$keyword =$_COOKIE['keyword'];

    $digikeyurl = 'http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors?keywords='.$keyword;
```

And get that variable using `$_GET['keywords']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 echo "<script language='javascript'>location.href='http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors?keywords='.$keyword. '"'</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$keyword =$_COOKIE['keyword'];
$digikeyurl = "http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors?keywords=$keyword";
```