# sending an email from HTML form, address in SQL

Tags: php, html

Using this example, [Add php variable inside echo statement as href link address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916966/add-php-variable-inside-echo-statement-as-href-link-address),

I am able to grab an email address from my SQL DB and make it clickable in my form.  The HTML looks like this:

Contact: blahblah@gmail.com

but when I either hover over if or click it, it adds the name of my domain before it.    So clicking the above tries to go to:

http://mydomainname.com/blahblah@gmail.com

Here is some of the code that generates my link

```
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                ob_start();

                echo "
....

<div class='eventContact'>Contact: <a href='".$tempcontact."'>$tempcontact</a></br></div>
                ";

                ob_end_clean();
            }
```

I am guessing it shouldn't be a 'a href' but not sure what it should be.

Comment: change it to `mailto: youremail@emailaddress.com`  -this will fire the users email client

Comment: <div class='eventContact'>Contact: <mailto(".$tempcontact."'.);''>$tempcontact</br></div>

Comment: What will make it clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment:

Change it to `mailto:youremail@emailaddress.com` -this will fire the users email client

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@emailaddress.com">Email me</a>
```

You can then set the subject of the email too if you want

```
<a href="mailto:youremail@emailaddress.com?Subject=Hi">Email me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, works now - for anyone else trying to do this I will post the end result:<div class='eventContact'>Contact: <a href='mailto:".$tempcontact.";'>$tempcontact</a></br></div>